# How to correctly install bucardo

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I am new to bucardo and I am trying my first install. I have postgresql-9.1 installed.

After installing all dependencies I have downloaded Bucardo-5.1.1.tar file, extract it and sucessfully install it using make according to bucardo site instructions.

The problem starts when I try to launch "bucardo_ctl". The bucardo_ctl script is not installed with bucardo-5.1.1 install script and ubuntu says I need to run "apt-get update bucardo" for installing bucardo_ctl.

The problem is that when I install bucardo from ubuntu repositories, it also installs postgresql-8.4, and bucardo from repository is version 4.

How can I install bucardo_ctl from bucardo-5.1.1?

Thank you very much

Regards

Paulo

Comment: In what directories did you look for `bucardo_ctl` to conclude that it was not installed?

Comment: Hi Daniel. I found the problem. Bucardo_ctl is not installed because bucardo_ctl was renamed to just bucardo since version 5. Found this information on the github repository for bucardo. The instructions on bucardo web site are out of date. I will try reinstalling everything to see if I can make it work. Anyway, do you know bucardo? If so I really need a hand on it.